# Intel Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 Drivers for Windows 8 (64 Bit) on Dell N7010

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, drivers, 64-bit, wimax

I cannot seem to find or get the required drivers for Intel Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 on windows 8 64bit on my Dell N7010 Laptop

I have wifi connectivity but all i get is max G speeds and no N speeds, transfering files on mapped drives is really slow as a result, this wasnt the case before, i dont care about wimax, but even those drivers would be appreciated incase i decide to sell in future...

Answer (score 3):

[These](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=21999&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208,%2064-bit*&DownloadType=Software%20Applications#help) are the drivers on the Intel website

Comment: nopes same error still missing http://i.imgur.com/TxVM6.png

Comment: @kindrudekid What's showing under Network Adapters? Do you get any error messages when you run the Intel installer?

Comment: nopes None error!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Intel Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect) to find your driver for you.

If it fails, you could also try all the software [listed here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Wireless%20Networking&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE%20WiMAX%20Adapters&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Centrino%C2%AE%20Advanced-N%20%2b%20WiMAX%206250).
I would suggest taking first at least a system restore point.